# What's the relationship between these numbers?

Tags: algorithm, math, algebra

I am trying to replicate a functionality of a built-in function, as the built-in functionality is not callable inside scripts, but I can't seem to figure out the how the 3rd parameter is calculated.

Basically you specify `a` and `b` and it returns `c`. So here is the result of some operations:

```
a   b   c

1   1   1
1   2   0.75
1   3   0.666667
1   4   0.625
1   5   0.6

2   1   0.75
2   2   0.5
2   3   0.416667
2   4   0.375
2   5   0.35
2   6   0.333333
2   7   0.321429
2   8   0.3125
2   9   0.305556
2   10  0.3

3   1   0.666667
3   2   0.416667
3   3   0.333333

4   1   0.625
4   2   0.375
4   3   0.291667
4   4   0.25

100 1   0.505
100 2   0.255
100 3   0.171667
100 10  0.055
```

Let me know if you need additional outputs.

Comment: Do you know whether this function is recursive or not?

Comment: is there a name for that functionality that could point out in the right direction ?

Comment: I don't have the source, but very sure it's not recursive.

Comment: You might want to plot in 3d, and possibly create a surface with a least-squares fit  I use *Mathematica* but I'm sure there are some open-source tools to do this basic plotting.

Comment: And it seems that a,b is the same as b,a - so 1,3=>0.66 as well as 3,1. That is a good hint.

Comment: Thanks guys, the function is unfortunately called "initialize" :O

Comment: I have found one more if f(a,b)=x then f(2a,2b)=x/2

Comment: @Yorye: That's the only thing I saw as well. I am trying to see how numbers like 0.666667 can be generated, so for instance 2/3 gives that.

Comment: So you're asking people to guess what this function does? Strictly speaking, it's not determinable from a finite set of outputs. It's like asking what's the next number in the sequence `1, 2, 3`; for any successor value `N` I can write a 4th degree polynomial that will produce the sequence `1, 2, 3, N`.

Comment: Not what it does. It's related to sizing, so a and b defines size like x and y, but the 3rd component is calculated from both, which I want to find out how to calculate it myself given the same inputs.

Comment: In what language has the original function been written? If it's C# it's easy to check the original code. If it's C++, there might be a chance to decompile the code or check the assembly code directly to determine what it does.

Comment: I will try to interpolate it.

Comment: It's C++ but the source is not there, I added C# to include more people.

Comment: Could you post the outputs for: (100,1) (100,2) (100,3) (100,10) (100,100) (1000,1) (1000,2) (1000,3) (1000,10) (1000,100). Big numbers often give good clues.

Comment: @Yorye, ok will add them now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For all of your sample the following formula provides the expected result:

```
C = (A + B) / (2 * A * B)
```

As ypercube pointed out in the comments this formula is the inverse of the [Harmonic mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean) or the arithmetic mean of the inverses.

Comment: Thanks a lot, let me try it out :O

Comment: Nice! How did you figure that out?

Comment: @YoryeNathan, convert the decimal numbers into natural fractions and you can see patterns emerging.

Comment: Nothing scientific, I've looked at the values and did some fiddling in excel. For the complete picture I've a Bsc in Compute science so  I've learned enough math  :)

Comment: You are the man, it seems like this is it :O

Comment: Yep, this is the inverse of the [Harmonic mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean). Or the harmonic mean of the inverses.

Comment: @nemesv: My bad, it's **not** the harmonic mean of the inverses.